# Sound in Chrome

Tags: sound, xubuntu, google-chrome, pulseaudio

Hi (I am a complete novice in all this!),

I run the latest version of Xubuntu on a small HTPC.

I recently began having problems with sound. All the sites I could find on the internet kept saying it's PulseAudio so I fiddled around with settings ect... I tried everything I could find on the internet to either fix or replace it and nothing worked.

I could not find a suitable replacement that would actually work and didn't require a degree in Linux to make work.

So, in the end I settled with removing Pulse completely. As I only use the computer for Plex, and that seems to be able to play audio directly to the sound card, there isn't a problem anymore.

That is, except for one problem. There is no sound at all from Chrome.

Is there anyway of getting chrome to do what Plex does and go directly for the sound card? or an extension for Chrome that does this???

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is indeed a problem with chrome and is supposed to be fixed in an upcoming version of chrome. until then, i reccomen using Mozilla Firefox as your browser.