# No sound on Xubuntu 14.04 on Acer C720

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed an Xubuntu 14.04 image from [HugeGreenBug](https://www.distroshare.com/distros/get/14/) and my audio stopped working after I rebooted during an upgrade a few hours after installation. I've looked at posts about this here and tried deleting my PulseAudio configuration, uninstalling alsa and pulse audio, restarting alsa, etc.

The problem started after I rebooted while updating packages, and VLC uninstallled itself. Audio was working at that point, but quit after reinstalling VLC and rebooting. Here is my [alsa info script output](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b4c7337eb1c7261499a99b8ddab098cdd6d408ba).

Comment: Note: HugeGreenBug is not an oficial Ubuntu/Xubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get system sound working by adding my UID to the audio group. I still am not getting audio in Chrome however, but that might just be a bug in Chrome at the moment, as was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473945/sound-in-chrome).

If anyone has any more Chrome specific suggestions, those would still be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the file `/etc/modules` contains:

```
chromeos_laptop
i2c-designware-core
i2c-designware-pci
i2c-designware-platform
```

If not, manually update it and then try rebooting the machine.

Comment: after adding those to /etc/modules, my application shortcuts for "pactl set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo toggle" and volume up and down work again, but still no sound.